# Any reference to an algorithm for finding the largest empty circle on a sphere (with great-circle distance)?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry, spherical-geometry

Given a set $S$ of 2D points in the plane, there are known algorithms for finding the *largest empty circle* ($LEC$) of the set of points.

The $LEC$ problem is stated in this way: find a $LEC$ whose center is in the closed Convex Hull of S, *empty* in that it contains no points in its interior, and *largest* in that there is no other such circle with strictly larger radius.

[O'Rourke](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6094/joseph-orourke) describes a simple $O(n^2)$ algorithm in his book "Computational Geometry in C" (the algorithm is attributed to G.T. Toussaint, 1983. Computing Largest Empty Circles with Location Constraints. *International Journal of Parallel Programming*, v12.5, pp 347-358.), the algorithm goes like this:

1. Compute the Voronoi Diagram $VD$ of the set of points
2. Compute the Convex Hull $CH$ of the set of points
3. The center of the $LEC$ is at one of the $VD$ vertexes inside the $CH$ **or** it is at an intersection between one of the $VD$ edges and $CH$.
4. For each candidate center compute the radius of the circle centered on it and update the maximum radius.

Now, on the plane, with $P=(P_x,P_y)$, the radius is computed with the distance $dist(P,C)=\sqrt{(P_x-C_x)^2+(P_y-C_y)^2}$ for a proper $P$.

I am interested in an algorithm for a similar problem: I have a set $S'$ of 3D points lying on a sphere of radius $R$ and I would like to find the equivalent of the $LEC$. I can assume that all points of $S'$ lie on a hemisphere.

In the sphere problem, the distances are measured by means of the *great-circle distance*.

With $S$ the 2D circle is the locus of points equidistant from a fixed point on the plane; with $S'$ the locus of points on the sphere equidistant (distance measured by the *great-circle distance*) from a fixed point on the sphere is the spherical curve usually called *small circle*. So instead of the *largest empty circle* maybe I can call what I am looking for the *largest empty small-circle*.

Is there any published algorithm for my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the same algorithm works.
Note the remarkable fact, first understood by Kevin Brown,
that the Voronoi diagram of points $P$ on a sphere is combinatorially identical 
to the (3D) convex hull of $P$: each face of the hull corresponds to a Voronoi vertex
(and to an empty circle). This leads to
an $O(n \log n)$ algorithm, as explained in this paper:

> Hyeon-Suk Na, Chung-Nim Lee, Otfried Cheong,
>   "Voronoi diagrams on the sphere." 
>   *Computational Geometry: Theory and Applications*, 23 (2002) 183–194.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=636913))

Here is a recent implementation article:

> Zheng, Xiaoyu, et al. "A Plane Sweep Algorithm for the Voronoi Tessellation of the Sphere." *Electronic-Liquid Crystal Communications* [online] (2011).
>   ([PDF download](http://e-lc.org/tmp/Xiaoyu__Zheng_2011_12_05_14_35_11.pdf).)

I can't resist re-sharing this image of a Vornoi diagram on a sphere from [an earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/86438/6094):

          
[image: VD on sphere]

          

<sup>[Mathematica image by Maxim Rytin](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagramOnASphere/).</sup>

Comment: Some more images... http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/voronoi/