# Volume of specials sets on sphere $S^N$

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Suppose I'm given $m$ points $\{q_i\}$ on the sphere $S^N$. I want to get a lower/upper bound for the volume of the following sets with respect to uniform probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on the sphere. Let
$$
A_i = \{ x \in S^N : (q_i,x) > (q_j,x) ~\forall j \neq i \}
$$
Is there (say) a formula for such a quantity in terms of the $q_i$? Suppose I know everything there is to know about the $q_i$, is there a general strategy for calculating such things?

Answer (score 3):

On a 2-sphere, such regions are spherical polygons (each of the inequalities in the definition of $A_i$ gives you a half-sphere). The area of such a polygon is given by a formula using the sum of angles of the polygon. So I am afraid you will first have to construct these Voronoi polygons. There are some algorithms for that.

In higher dimensions, the situation must be worse.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Yuri's answer:

In response to the earlier MO question, [Delaunay triangulations and convex hulls](https://mathoverflow.net/q/86420/6094), I posted this image:

---

[image: VD on sphere]
      
<sup>Image by Maxim Rytin in a [Mathematica Demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagramOnASphere/).</sup>

---

See that MO question for related references.